# Submitting a form in asp .net MVC, various errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TrafficDate()
    {
        CalendarModel model = new CalendarModel();
        model.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        model.EditMode = false;
        //model.TrafficDates = TrafficData.GeTrafficDatesPerMonth(model.SelectedDate);

        return View(model);
    }

    // GET: TrafficDate
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TrafficDate(DateTime date, bool editMode = false)
    {
        CalendarModel model = new CalendarModel();
        model.SelectedDate = date;
        model.EditMode = editMode;
        //model.TrafficDates = TrafficData.GeTrafficDatesPerMonth(model.SelectedDate);

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult TrafficDate(CalendarModel model)
    {
```

The topmost ActionResult was added because it kept complaining that there was no parameterless method. now it complains that there is an ambiguity between the two methods that have HttpGet in the tag above, when I switch the parameterless to be HttpPost instead, then I get the same thing between the two that are HttpPost.

I want my submit button to go to the bottom method of the three. but it seems it wants a parameterless method, does that mean the model is empty when I click submit?

here's a part of the .cshtml file

```
    @model Intern.Models.CalendarModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Trafikkalender";
    //Layout = "_Layout";
}

<script>

</script>


<form method="post" id="form">
    <div id="hiddenFields" hidden="hidden">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedDate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EditMode, new { id = "editMode" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubmitMode, new { id = "submitMode" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RegisterPersonOnThisResourceId, new { id = "registerForResourceId" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PersonToRegister, new { id = "selectedPerson" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TimeFrom, new { id = "hiddenTimeFrom" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TimeTo, new { id = "hiddenTimeTo" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Message, new { id = "hiddenMessage" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewTrafficType, new { id = "hiddenNewTrafficType" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewTrafficText, new { id = "hiddenNewTrafficText" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewTrafficNumTrains, new { id = "hiddenSelectedNewTrafficNumTrains" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewTrafficNumConductors, new { id = "hiddenSelectedNewTrafficNumConductors" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CopyTraffic, new { id = "hiddenCopyTraffic" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewTrafficDate, new { id = "hiddenNewTrafficDate" })
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1 id="header" class="page-header">Trafik - @((DayNames)((int)Model.SelectedDate.DayOfWeek)) den @Model.SelectedDate.Day @((MonthNames)Model.SelectedDate.Month) @Model.SelectedDate.Year</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Föregående dag", "TrafficDate", new { date = Model.SelectedDate.AddDays(-1), editMode = Model.EditMode }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Nästa dag", "TrafficDate", new { date = Model.SelectedDate.AddDays(1), editMode = Model.EditMode }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">

        @if (UserData.isInRole(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name), "Administratör"))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Redigera dag(beta)", "ToggleEditMode", "TrafficDate", new { date = Model.TrafficDate.Date, editMode = Model.EditMode }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    <input onclick="javascript: EditDay();" type="button" value="Redigera dag" id="editDayButton" name="editDayButton" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <input onclick="javascript: CancelEditDay();" type="button" value="Avsluta redigering" id="cancelEditDayButton" name="cancelEditDayButton" class="btn btn-primary hidden" />
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "PrintDay", new { date = Model.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-print" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        @if (Model.EditMode)
        {
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @for (int ti = 0; ti < Model.TrafficDate.Traffics.Count; ti++)
                    {
                        <div class="panel panel-default form-group">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                @(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TrafficDate.Traffics[ti].TrafficType, TrafficData.GetTrafficTypes(Model.TrafficDate.Traffics[ti].TrafficType.ToString()), new { @class = "ddlTrafficType", @id = "ddlTrafficType_" + ti }))
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TrafficDate.Traffics[ti].Published, new { @class = "cbTrafficPublished", @id = "cbPublished_" + ti }) Publicerad
                                [<input type="button" value="Radera" class="deleteTraffic btn btn-link NoBorder NoBackGround" data-id="@Model.TrafficDate.Traffics[ti].Id" data-url="@Url.Action("DeleteTraffic")" data-confirm="Är du säker på att du vill radera denna trafik?" />]
                                <input type="button" class="saveTraffic btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right" value="Spara (@Model.TrafficDate.Traffics[ti].TrafficType.ToString())" data-url="@Url.Action("SaveTraffic")" data-id="@Model.TrafficDate.Traffics[ti].Id" data-confirm="Är du säker på att du vill skriva över de nuvarande inställningarna på denna trafik?" />
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save traffic (beta)" />

                            </div>
```

the submit button is on the second to last line of the code cutout here. 
is the problem in my .cshtml file? or have I defined the controller methods wrong in some way? the hiddenfields in the beginning was for a javascript I made to handle the saving of things, but I want to get rid of the javascript and make this the correct way.

Also. the form-group class in the code, I saw that in an example, is that important? do I need that in every div? or is it enough to have it in the div that surrounds the whole block of html involved in the thing I want to submit?

Comment: For your get, you either need to specify the parameters as optional in the route config and the action signature or remove them if not need on the initial Get.

Comment: I'm new to mvc, how exactly do I do this?

Comment: I think you can actually get away with allowing the parameters to be null in the signature. I'll post for you to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TrafficDate(DateTime? date, bool? editMode = false)
{
     return View();
}
```

Then remove the parameterless TrafficDate action leaving only your post.

I've tried locally and it seems ok
thanks

Comment: thank you, it works. I also had some issues with my model that became apparent, with default constructors. but it works perfect now :)